# Getting incorrect yyyy format in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

One of my user facing Date picker issue and it looks like this. I don't why yyyy format is like this.

Does anyone face this before?

[image]

Comment: Please share more detail about your code.

Comment: What's your locale?

Comment: @Larme I already asked user to provide more information. But seems its locale issue, So I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your locale it's different than Gregorian. If you want your `DateFormatter` should always Gregorian calender please check the below extension.

```
extension DateFormatter {

private static var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

class func initWithSafeLocale(withDateFormat dateFormat: String? = nil) -> DateFormatter {

    dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    if dateFormat != nil, let format = dateFormat {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    }else{
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    }
    return dateFormatter
}
```

}

```
extension Date {

var dateFormatted: String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter.initWithSafeLocale(withDateFormat: DateFormatorEnum.yyyyMMDD.rawValue)
    return  formatter.string(from: self as Date)
}
```

}

Usage:

```
self.txtDateOfBirth.text = datePicker.date.dateFormatted
```

It will display date picker on local but text filed always have Georgen date.

Cheers!

Comment: Georgen? Don't you mean Gregorian?

Comment: Yes! , Apologies for the typo.